# nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use) on docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am trying to get the default webpage from nginx loaded but I cannot connect to port 80 over http after the container is running.

I am running docker 1.9.9

The steps I took are as followed:

I created a Docker file that this:

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10

RUN echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install lsof
RUN apt-get install net-tools
RUN apt-get install psmisc
RUN apt-get -y install curl

ADD supervisor.nginx.conf /etc/supervisor.d/nginx.conf

CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n

RUN rm -Rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/logs/
RUN touch /etc/nginx/logs/error.log

RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/logs/
RUN touch /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log

ADD ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

copy ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

THe docker file copies the nginx config file below into `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and creates a symlink to this file for `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

```
server {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
    access_log        off;
    log_not_found     off;
    expires           5d;
  }

  # deny access to . files, for security
  #
  location ~ /\. {
     access_log off;
     log_not_found off;
     deny all;
  }
}
```

I then built the image with:

```
docker build -t dnginx
```

I started the container with:

```
docker run --name d3 -d -p 80:80 dnginx
```

I then found the ip address and tried to connect

```
curl http://172.17.0.2
```

Which returned

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 80: Operation timed out

I opened a bash shell in the container and ran `nginx` which returned:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

If I run `netstat --listen` I get:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:80                    *:*                     LISTEN
```

If I run `netstat -ltnp | grep :80` I get:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I have absolutely no idea what is happening.

The same thing happens if I connect just to the nginx image.

Comment: If you run `netstat --listen` on the host OS what is listening on port 80?

Comment: I get:  tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN

Comment: This means that there is something listening on your port 80...

Comment: lsof -i :80 returns:

nginx     1 root    6u  IPv4 239214      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

should I kill this?

Comment: I don't understand what the 98: already in use means

Comment: The 98: already in use means that there is a process which is using that particular IP/port address. You should understand which process is and you can do it via `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :80`. Once you've understood which process it is, if you're not interested in it you can kill it and try again..

Comment: Do you need supervisord? It seems that you're running just one process (nginx). You can just run it without supervisord to see if it's working or not. That way, you'll know if it causes the problem.

Comment: Same deal with supervisord disabled

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've tried your `Dockerfile` and it has worked as expected. The only changes I made were removing anything referring to `supervisord` and adding

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

at the end of the `Dockerfile`.

When a container starts, its networking namespace is completely isolated from the host and from the other containers, and the only processes are the one started by the ENTRIPOINT or CMD directives and its children, so I think that the `nginx` process that you see running in the container is exactly the one which is run by `supervisord`.

Are you sure that `172.17.0.2` is the current IP of the docker container?
The container IP is not stable, and it varies depending on how many containers are running on your host and the order on which they have been started.

You expose the http port on the host with the run option '-p 80:80', so you should be able to access it on docker host using `curl 127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 25):

I have the same issue these days, but i have to run multi-process, so removing supervisord is not a solution for me.

Simply add `-g "daemon off;"` flag to supervisor nginx program command solves the problem. That is

`[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"`

It seems that all process in a container must be run in the foreground, even managed by supervisord tools

Comment: This is the actual solution when supervisor is required. Thank you!

Comment: This solution works for those who use supervisord.conf

Comment: Thanks for this! My takeaway: When supervisor starts nginx in daemon mode (background), it starts and goes into the background. Supervisor now thinks nginx is dead and attempts to restart it. Since nginx is already running in the background, it complains that the port is already taken. The fix is to tell nginx to run in the foreground so supervisor can track it (same is true for a plain docker image running nginx without supervisor) - this can be done via the CLI option as suggested in this answer and also in the nginx config file.

Comment: This is not working for me, I am using supervisord for running the commands, I also tried to change the nginx port to 8080. It is giving same error