# nginx: [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied) on Docker

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Summing up: It run in my Windows, however not in my Linux Deepin (I'm meeting this world).

After install the docker CE and docker compose, I can't run anything web server, apache and nginx. In this case I'm using nginx, but without success.

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting php_php_1   ... done
Starting php_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to php_nginx_1, php_php_1
nginx_1  | 2019/04/19 19:09:56 [emerg] 1#1: socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] socket() 0.0.0.0:80 failed (13: Permission denied)
php_1    | [19-Apr-2019 19:09:57] ERROR: failed to create new listening socket: socket(): Permission denied (13)
php_1    | [19-Apr-2019 19:09:57] ERROR: failed to create new listening socket: socket(): Permission denied (13)
php_1    | [19-Apr-2019 19:09:57] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
php_1    | [19-Apr-2019 19:09:57] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
php_nginx_1 exited with code 1
php_php_1 exited with code 78
```

Note: When I installed I have runned it below before and I did logout

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
$ sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
```

Even though I don't have anything in my port **:80**.

```
netstat --listen | grep :80
```

I followed this topic [33650820](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650820/nginx-emerg-bind-to-0-0-0-080-failed-98-address-already-in-use-on-docke) and without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours, I got... only disable AppArmor on Linux Deepin.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/default/grub.d
$ echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT apparmor=0"' 
| sudo tee /etc/default/grub.d/apparmor.cfg
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo reboot
```